# Sql, print only rows with a value that appear at least n times

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

I have two tables created in sql.
**players(code(PK),surname,name)**
and
**errors(playererrorcode(PK),date,money,code(FK to players))**

---

So two tables looks like:
Players:

```
A1  Surname1  Name1
A2  Surname2  Name2
```

And errors for example:

```
E1  2015/7/10  10$  A1
E2  2015/2/20  50$  A1
E3  2015/1/30  40$  A2
E4  2015/5/20  30$  A1
```

---

Well, now, i have to print(select in this language) ONLY players that have at least 3 errors!
 In this case i want to print only the row that include: surname and name of who have at least 3 errors, then it have to print only surname1 and name1.

How to do that?

Comment: Is this supposed to work in MySQL, SQL Server and postgres?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use the **Count** aggregation to get the number of errors per player and use **Having** to specify the number of error required -- like this:

```
SELECT
p.surname,
p.name,
FROM players as p
INNER JOIN errors as e
on p.code=e.code
GROUP BY 
p.surname,
p.name
HAVING 
COUNT(e.playererrorcode)>=3
```